# I want to save data in two tables when i click the button Yii2

Tags: php, database, yii2

For example, I have two tables. One called "PedidoReservaQuarto" and another "PedidoReserva". What I want to do is this, I want to save the data in both tables when I click the button. But first I need to enter data in the table "PedidoReservaQuarto" because of the id.

**My action controller**

```
public function actionCreate($id)
{
    $modelPedidoReservaQuarto = new PedidoReservaQuarto();
    $modelPedidoReserva = new PedidoReserva();
    $modelPedidoReservaQuarto->quartoId = $id;
    $modelPedidoReservaQuarto->save();
    
    if ($modelPedidoReserva->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelPedidoReserva->save()) {

        return $this->redirect(['create', 'id' => $modelPedidoReserva->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('../pedido-reserva/create', [
        'model' => $modelPedidoReserva,
    ]);
}
```

**Model PedidoReservaQuarto**

```
public function getPedidoReservas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PedidoReserva::className(), ['reservaQuartoId' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * Gets query for [[Quarto]].
 *
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getQuarto()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Quarto::className(), ['id' => 'quartoId']);
}
```

**Model PedidoReserva**

```
public function getReservaQuarto()
{
    return $this->hasOne(PedidoReservaQuarto::className(), ['id' => 'reservaQuartoId']);
}
```

Comment: Edit your question so it is clear what your exact question is and what isn't working right now.

Comment: Your question is not clear   .. try add  a proper data sample  and the expected  result  ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in you form you have the data you need for both the model and send these data using method post (click submit button)
and you must obtain the id from modelPedidoReserva for assign to model modelPedidoReservaQuarto you could try

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $modelPedidoReservaQuarto = new PedidoReservaQuarto();
        $modelPedidoReserva = new PedidoReserva();
        $modelPedidoReservaQuarto->quartoId = $id;
        $modelPedidoReservaQuarto->save();
        
        if ($modelPedidoReserva->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelPedidoReserva->save()) {
            $modelPedidoReservaQuarto->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            $modelPedidoReservaQuarto->quartoId = $modelPedidoReserva->id;
            $modelPedidoReservaQuarto-save();
        }

        return $this->render('../pedido-reserva/create', [
            'model' => $modelPedidoReserva,
        ]);
    }
```

once you have saved  the $modelPedidoReserva  the related  id is already available ..